# Explain this witchcraft!!! (in Perl, with Moose and namespace::autoclean)

Tags: perl, moose, symbol-table, mop

So these days I'm working with a project that uses Perl and Moose. I understand Moose is built on MOP. I'm not too familiar with MOP, and I've encountered something I don't understand, and I could use a theoretical explanation. Here is the module `namespace::autoclean`'s documentation:

```
SYNOPSIS
    package Foo;
    use namespace::autoclean;
    use Some::Package qw/imported_function/;

    sub bar { imported_function('stuff') }

    # later on:
    Foo->bar;               # works
    Foo->imported_function; # will fail. imported_function got cleaned after compilation
```

So, back before I ever used Moose, the way that you called a method on an object was: the Perl interpreter would look up that method in the symbol table of the package that your object was blessed into (then, if not found, consider `@ISA` inheritance and the like). The way it called an imported function from within the package was: it looked up the name of the function in the symbol table of the package. As far as I've been aware to date, that means the same symbol table, either way, so this behavior should be impossible.

My initial inspection of the source was not productive. In broad terms, what is different when using Moose, MOP, and namespace::autoclean, that this sort of trickery becomes possible?

**ed.** To be especially clear, if I were to replace `use namespace::autoclean` with

```
CHECK { undef *Foo::imported_function }
```

then the `Foo->bar;` call described in the documentation would crash, because `Foo->bar` doesn't know where to find `imported_function`.

Comment: Just on a long shot: would predeclaring via `use subs qw/imported_function/;` stop the autocleaning? Or importing *before* loading `namespace::autoclean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. For

```
some_sub()
```

`some_sub` is resolved at compile time. For

```
$o->some_method()
```

`some_method` is resolved at runtime. It cannot be done at compile-time since it depends on the value of `$o`.

Comment: Ah. And so if I did `sub bar { no strict 'refs'; my $func = "imported_function"; &$func('stuff') }` it *wouldn't* work.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing here that is non-standard. The line

```
use Some::Package qw/imported_function/;
```

imports `imported_function` into the current package, so `Foo::imported_function` is the same subroutine as `Some::Package::imported_function`. That assumes that `Some::Package` inherits from `Exporter` to do the necessary manipulation of the symbol tables.

The calls are method calls, so `Foo->bar` is the same as `Foo::bar('Foo')`. The only special thing here is that the magic that has been done by the `import` function from `Exporter` is undone at the end of compile time by `namespace::autoclean`.

I haven't looked at the code for this module, but since a package's symbol table is just a hash (known as a *stash*, for *symbol table hash*) it would be easy to preserve its state at one point and restore it afterwards. So I would guess `namespace::autoclean` takes a snapshot of the symbol table when it is loaded and the restores that state at the end of compilation time. This can conveniently be done in a [`CHECK` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END) which behaves like a `BEGIN` block but is executed at the end of compilation and before the run starts.

Comment: "So I would guess namespace::autoclean takes a snapshot of the symbol table when it is loaded and the restores that state at the end of compilation time." Compile-time manipulation of the symbol table *is* straightforward, but the resolution of the imported method call `sub bar { imported_function('stuff') }` which happens when you call `Foo->bar` ... **occurs at runtime**. You will observe, for instance, that this doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/4708620 Clearly, this is not a full explanation of the mechanism that is at work.

Comment: @fennec Of course it does. However, you `undef`ed the sub itself, instead of deleting only the name from the stash → `delete ${Foo::}{pseudoimport}`, and it works. (for many names: `delete @{Foo::}{@list_of_names};`). Of course, such barbarism destroys *any* variable with the same name as well).

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. So where does the code for Foo::pseudoimport live after `delete ${Foo::}{pseudoimport}`?

Comment: @fennec You can have anonymous subs: `my $anon = sub {...};` Where does that live? *Not* in the stash. It is accessible as long as it has a reference count. Names and values are distinct: `my $x = 1; $hash{key} = $x; delete $hash{key} # does $x still have a value?` Delete just removes an entry from a hash, and doesn't touch the value

Comment: Hmm. It seems you're saying that my assertion that the resolution of `pseudoimport()` occurs at runtime is **false** and I was wrong. If so, that's simple enough and explains everything.